# How to open a file from bash command line in the already open Emacs instead of a new instance?

Tags: command-line, bash, emacs

How to open a file from bash command line in the already open Emacs instead of a new instance? When I type

```
$ emacs file.txt
```

it opens a new Emacs instance, instead of opening the file in the existing Emacs instance. Mac OS X 10.6.8. and

```
GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0, NS apple-appkit-1038.36)
```

of 2012-02-27 on beta.macosforge.org

Answer (score 9, accepted):

what you are looking for is emacs server mode. Add this line to your .emacs file:

```
(server-start)
```

Then, open the file using emacsclient:

```
emacsclient foobar.txt
```

Have a look at [this](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.fr/2008/12/opening-emacsclient-windows-on-current.html) page for more information.

---

To avoid having to start emacs manually or setting it to auto-start, you could write a little function that tries connecting to a running server (by running `emacsclient`)  and if not, runs `emacs` instead. Add this to your shell's configuration file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`):

```
emacs(){ 
    emacsclient "$@" 2>/dev/null || /usr/bin/emacs "$@" 
}
```

Now, simply running `emacs file` will either start the server or connect to an existing instance.

Comment: But then it means that one has to keep track and remember whether he/she already started a server or not... Is there a better way?

Comment: @Dror not at all, when you add this to your emacs configuration file, it will simply launch the server the first time you run emacs and then open all subsequent files in that instance. You don't need to keep track of anything at all.

Comment: But if `emacs` was not started, then `emacsclient` will yield an error.

Comment: @Dror ah, yes, I see what you mean. See updated answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If emacs server hasn't been started, the command does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I cannot recall where I found the following solution. Sorry. However, since it worked optimally for me I add it here.

Make sure that your `.emacs` starts the emacs server.

```
(server-start)
```

Next, in your `.bashrc` define the function:

```
function run_emacs
{
/usr/bin/emacsclient "$1" &
}
```

and set the environment variables:

```
export EDITOR=emacsclient
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=emacs
```

Finally, define the alias:

```
alias emacs='run_emacs'
```