# How to open a file with emacsclient without console-hijacking?

Tags: windows, emacs, cmd.exe, console

I set up an `emacsclient` according to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/462463/571014), but there's a little detail that annoys me **a lot**.

```
emacsclient file.txt
```

opens a file in an active view, everything looks smooth except for the:

> Waiting for Emacs...

thingy similar to `gedit file.txt` if gedit isn't running i.e. it hijacks the console and outputs whatever the binary outputs to console until I kill the view with that file (it triggers `file.txt has some active clients, kill anyway?`) or until I close the console.

So, my question is - how to avoid this and make `emacsclient file.txt` behave like a common `gedit file.txt` or for Windowsers `notepad++ file.txt` when the instance of the program is already there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently that's an [intended behavior](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/XY-ZDB-Rmq8) where a user is supposed to let the console know when the file editing is finished with <kbd>Ctrl + x</kbd><kbd>#</kbd>, but manual comes to the rescue once again!

```
emacsclient --no-wait file.txt
emacsclient -n file.txt
```

this call behaves like expected from common file editors.